# Laravel 9 add new key and values using crossJoin collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-collection

so i have a table **Items** my table has a row *`product`* and `price` only. my goal is how to
add key with values using crossJoin collect

here is my code when fetching all data in my table im using `each` collect to add new row with values

```
public function ProductList(){
    $items = Item::all(); //rows only 'product', 'price'
    $Brand = collect($items)->each(function($newRow){
        $newRow->color = 'Blue'; // adding this in row
        $newRow->size = 'Large'; // adding this in row
    });
    return $Brand ;
}
```

here is the output of that code

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Lee",
"price": "500",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
{
"id": 2,
"product": "Jeans",
"price": "400",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
{
"id": 3,
"product": "Guess",
"price": "300",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
{
"id": 4,
"product": "Levis",
"price": "200",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
}
]
```

in the output `color` and `size` has been added to key with the values of `blue` and `large`.
but that it's not the output i want to show. i want is each items color have a BLUE , BLACK , WHITE and size LARGE , MEDIUM , SMALL

like this code: ( i will not include the price )

```
   public function test(){
        $item = ['Lee','Jeans','Guess','Levis'];
        $size = ['LARGE','MEDIUN','SMALL'];
        $color = ['BLUE','BLACK','WHITE'];
        return collect($item)->crossJoin($size,$color);
    }
```

the output of this

```
  [
    [
    "Lee",
    "LARGE",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Lee",
    "LARGE",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Lee",
    "LARGE",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Lee",
    "MEDIUN",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Lee",
    "MEDIUN",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Lee",
    "MEDIUN",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Lee",
    "SMALL",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Lee",
    "SMALL",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Lee",
    "SMALL",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Jeans",
    "LARGE",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Jeans",
    "LARGE",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Jeans",
    "LARGE",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Jeans",
    "MEDIUN",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Jeans",
    "MEDIUN",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Jeans",
    "MEDIUN",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Jeans",
    "SMALL",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Jeans",
    "SMALL",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Jeans",
    "SMALL",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Guess",
    "LARGE",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Guess",
    "LARGE",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Guess",
    "LARGE",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Guess",
    "MEDIUN",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Guess",
    "MEDIUN",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Guess",
    "MEDIUN",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Guess",
    "SMALL",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Guess",
    "SMALL",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Guess",
    "SMALL",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Levis",
    "LARGE",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Levis",
    "LARGE",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Levis",
    "LARGE",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Levis",
    "MEDIUN",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Levis",
    "MEDIUN",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Levis",
    "MEDIUN",
    "WHITE"
    ],
    [
    "Levis",
    "SMALL",
    "BLUE"
    ],
    [
    "Levis",
    "SMALL",
    "BLACK"
    ],
    [
    "Levis",
    "SMALL",
    "WHITE"
    ]
  ]
```

so i tried this code but the output i want is not like this.

```
  public function ProductList(){
        $items = Item::all(); //rows only 'product', 'price'
        $statusBrand = collect($items)->each(function($newRow){
            $newRow->color = 'Blue'; // adding this in row
            $newRow->size = 'Large'; // adding this in row
        })->crossJoin(['BLUE','WHITE','LARGE'],['LARGE','MEDIUM','SMALL']);
        return $statusBrand;
    }
```

output of this:

```
[
[
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Lee",
"price": "500",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Lee",
"price": "500",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Lee",
"price": "500",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Lee",
"price": "500",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Lee",
"price": "500",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Lee",
"price": "500",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Lee",
"price": "500",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Lee",
"price": "500",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Lee",
"price": "500",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 2,
"product": "Jeans",
"price": "400",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 2,
"product": "Jeans",
"price": "400",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 2,
"product": "Jeans",
"price": "400",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 2,
"product": "Jeans",
"price": "400",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 2,
"product": "Jeans",
"price": "400",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 2,
"product": "Jeans",
"price": "400",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 2,
"product": "Jeans",
"price": "400",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 2,
"product": "Jeans",
"price": "400",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 2,
"product": "Jeans",
"price": "400",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 3,
"product": "Guess",
"price": "300",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 3,
"product": "Guess",
"price": "300",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 3,
"product": "Guess",
"price": "300",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 3,
"product": "Guess",
"price": "300",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 3,
"product": "Guess",
"price": "300",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 3,
"product": "Guess",
"price": "300",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 3,
"product": "Guess",
"price": "300",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 3,
"product": "Guess",
"price": "300",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 3,
"product": "Guess",
"price": "300",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 4,
"product": "Levis",
"price": "200",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 4,
"product": "Levis",
"price": "200",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 4,
"product": "Levis",
"price": "200",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"BLUE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 4,
"product": "Levis",
"price": "200",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 4,
"product": "Levis",
"price": "200",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 4,
"product": "Levis",
"price": "200",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"WHITE",
"SMALL"
],
[
{
"id": 4,
"product": "Levis",
"price": "200",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"LARGE"
],
[
{
"id": 4,
"product": "Levis",
"price": "200",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"MEDIUM"
],
[
{
"id": 4,
"product": "Levis",
"price": "200",
"color": "Blue",
"size": "Large"
},
"LARGE",
"SMALL"
]
]
```

in that code the crossJoin data entries has been added outside of the data array
the output i want to show is the `color` and `size` will be add in the data each of them

Comment: editted the title and tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your scenario by `MySQL` raw query. I've created a `items` table which has all your mentioned `products` as shown in the `screenshot`

[image]

I wrote following `query`:

```
SELECT items.*, colors_table.*, sizes_table.* FROM `items` 

#temp table for colors
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT "Blue" as color
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT "Black" as color
   UNION ALL
   SELECT "White" as color
    
) as colors_table

#temp table for sizes
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT "LARGE" as size
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "MEDIUM" as size
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "SMALL" as size
    
) as sizes_table
```

got below **output**:

[image]

I hope that'll help you and let me know if you need help to convert above `mysql` query to `laravel builder` query.

Comment: yes please, can you convert it into laravel builder? is it possible to use crossJoin like the way i did in my code. i wanna try my table items only.. without using table color or size.. i wanna use only text from the code.